# Why is this function returning 0 rows when the data types are correct?

Tags: sql-server

When the function is defined like this it will return the correct rows.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[exampleFunction](
 @GUID VARCHAR(20)--NUMERIC(16,0)
,@BrowseName VARCHAR(200)
)
```

But when I use Numeric(16,0), which is the correct data type for the data that's being passed, I receive 0 rows.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[exampleFunction](
 @GUID NUMERIC(16,0)
,@BrowseName VARCHAR(200)
)
```

The function is returning a BIT. Basically the function finds the GUID then compares the BrowseTreeName.

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to provide us more of the code than this. Also, why aren't you using `uniqueidentifier` if it's a GUID?

Comment: What we need in order to help: table definition(s); sample data; querying code; expected result; actual result. Note that it's highly likely that in producing that lot you will work out what's wrong yourself...

Comment: Have you increased your Numeric value to 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just a guess based on your parameter name (@GUID), but a GUID is not actually "numeric", see [uniqueidentifier (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx).  A 16 byte GUID value does not map properly to a numeric(16,0).

Why not just define the @GUID parameter as a `uniqueidentifier` data type?